# Selenium Webdriver (node.js) take screenshot and save test results

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I started developing tests for a website application and I have some problems.

I'm using Node.js, webdriver, chromedriver and selenium rc.

The questions are:
1. How do I make a screenshot and save it in the same folder as the script.
2. Is there a way to save the test logs for a test case? For example, if check for an element on the page and don't find it, how do I output that?

Comment: Don't ask two questions at once - this makes it more complicated and hence less useful for others. You could e.g. fix this problem by removing the "how do I save the test logs" part of the question.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For saving the test logs you typically use a test runner. When you check if an element is on the page and you can't find it then you raise an exception (typically an assertion error) and the test runner will record this and mark it as a failed test. [In the documentation they suggest you use Mocha](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Writing_Tests).

As for saving a screenshot to disk, the [the api](http://webdriver.io/docs.html#saveScreenshot) looks like this

```
driver.takeScreenshot().then(
    function(image, err) {
        require('fs').writeFile('out.png', image, 'base64', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: seems like it's not working...
i use selenium-webdriver, not webdriverjs. Dunno if there's any difference between them.

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Installing_from_NPM, What's the actual problem you are seeing Paz? If you want good answers on StackOverflow you have to be super specific.

Comment: `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'saveScreenshot'
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\*** ** Automation\User-Login.js:28:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3`

Comment: Okay, yeah I was using a different library. Try my updated answer against vanilla selenium.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks, I appreciate.
You forgot to close the bracket here `function(err { ` :)

Comment: This code doesn't wait for the file to be written to resolve the promise, or reject the promise when an error is thrown

Answer (score 14):

Adapting [aychedee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22938848/1318694)'s answer into a complete promise that will resolve after the file is written and reject on write failure:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises

function takeScreenshot(driver, file){
  return driver.takeScreenshot()
    .then(image => fsp.writeFile(file, image, 'base64'))
}
```

Or in an ESM [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function

```
import { writeFile } from 'node:fs/promises'

async function takeScreenshot(driver, file){
  let image = await driver.takeScreenshot()
  await writeFile(file, image, 'base64')
}
```

Comment: There is an `)` in excess in the async function.

Answer (score 7):

Just for the record, this is how you take a screenshot with [WebdriverJS](http://webdriver.io):

```
var webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs'),
    client = webdriverjs.remote({
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        }
    });

client
    .init()
    .url('http://google.com')
    .saveScreenshot(__dirname + '/googleScreenshot.png')
    .end();
```

You can also use [WebdriverCSS](https://github.com/webdriverjs/webdrivercss) to take screenshots. It is a plugin for WebdriverJS to do CSS regression tests. It is pretty much the same like [PhantomCSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS).