# Selenium routine works the first time, but subsequent runs fail

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this routine, using selenium-webdriver for NPM -  `require('selenium-webdriver')`:

```
       function run(){
          driver.get(cdthost + '/#!/home');
          driver.navigate().refresh(); // same problem, with or without this line
          let acqId = acq._id;
          assert(acqId, 'acqId is not defined.');
          // on the next line we wait to ensure that the page is loaded
          driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id(`open-editing-acqId-${acqId}`)), 3000);
          driver.findElement(By.id(`open-editing-acqId-${acqId}`)).click();
          let file = path.resolve($root + '/csv-data/IT-DE-Jasper.csv');
          let el = driver.findElement(By.id(`import-file-acqId-${acqId}`));
          driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(el), 2000);
          el.sendKeys(file);
          return driver.findElement(By.id(`submit-file-acqId-${acqId}`)).click().then(function () {
            return Promise.delay(2000)
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('\n\n', ' => Suman caught promise rejection => ', err.stack || err);
            return Promise.reject(err);
          });
       }
```

I call it once, and it works perfectly. I call it again, and it cannot find any elements on the page, even if I call refresh().

Any idea why this would work the first time, but not after that?

Comment: Have you been able to confirm that the 2nd time it runs you're actually on the page you expect? Are you creating a new driver every time you run it to make sure there aren't leftover cookies or something from a previous run that might make the page appear differently? This doesn't sounds like a fun issue...

Comment: LOL yeah not fun; I was thinking of just recreating the driver each time, but that seemed like overkill; but now that explicitly calling refresh doesn't work, maybe I will try recreating the driver.

Comment: @mrfreester I assume it would be on the right page, because I explicity call  driver.get(cdthost + '/#!/home');, and cdthost is a constant.

Comment: I don't think recreating the driver is the right approach, that's overkill, something else is wrong

Comment: My first step with things like this is to take a look at the [screenshot on failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22938045/1183506). It's worth the work to get screenshots setup for cases like this.

Comment: yeah, I can't get a screenshot on the second pass, so it appears that this line  driver.get(cdthost + '/#!/home'); doesn't ever complete on the second pass.

Comment: ok well, I have an answer, annoying/disappointing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, well this solved it:

```
 let passCount = 0;

 // ...
function run(){
 if(passCount < 1){
    driver.get(cdthost + '/#!/home');
  }
  else{
    driver.navigate().refresh();
  }

  passCount++;
 }
```

kind of disappointing...I will file an issue with the selenium-webdriver folks.

Another way which might work (untested) is like so:

```
let promise = null;

function getHomePage(){

  if(!promise){
     promise = driver.get(cdthost + '/#!/home');
   }

  return promise;
}

function run(){
  return getHomePage().then(function(){

  });
}
```

but I am not sure if this is more ideal, or less ideal.

Comment: Interesting, it's almost like the promise never resolves because the page doesn't end up doing another get since it's already on the page for some reason...

Comment: yeah, it's bad because this means you can't easily parallelize calls to run()

Comment: fwiw, if you're wanting to do parallel, having a clean driver per thread makes a lot of sense. Especially if you're running these on a grid or a similar service like saucelabs or browserstack. Which would also mitigate this issue. That being said, I'm not sure I totally understand this scenario so maybe that makes no sense for this case :)

Comment: Yeah not separate threads - but essentially interleaving execution - I am new to selenium, but I doubt I need a separate driver for each..but maybe.

Comment: Hey Corey, sure if you have a solution, please post as an answer