# How to render top of page to png via headless browser?

Tags: c#, node.js, automated-tests, user-experience, headless-browser

I'm trying to dynamically generate images for the og:image preview for a particular urls.

Given the designs/stack the easiest option for layout seems to be html/css/reactjs, so just trying to render out to an image using a headless browser of some kind.

Ideal would be js libraries or npm packages, but happy to use any stack to do the rendering (c#, java, anything). If I can't find something thinking maybe have to adapt something used in ux testing?

(That is, I guess I sort of need something like browsershots but only for one browser, only the top section of the page, and ideally running on my server).

Any ideas or suggestions greatly appreciated  thank you.

Comment: Well, how are you currently automating the browser? Selenium? Puppeteer? Something else? I'd start with looking to see if whichever one you're using suppots screenshots. As this is a general "please recommend a library to me" question (explicitly defined as off-topic - see the help section), I'm going to vote to close this.

Comment: huh? I'm not using a library I'm asking how to do this

Comment: Fair enough, but the _"Ideal would be js libraries or npm packages"_ part comes across as if you are. I'd suggest editing that.

Comment: I looked up https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and have rephrased the question to make it more clear that this is 
- a specific programming problem (how to save out a png)  
- involving software tools commonly used by programmers (nodejs, specifcally)
and has 
- a practical, answerable problem (pretty sure this is possible just dont know how) that is unique to software development (im not testing or using a tool i need  write custom code here)

Comment: Anyway, as I suggested in my initial comment, this seems to be a trivial task with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938045/selenium-webdriver-node-js-take-screenshot-and-save-test-results/22938848) and with [Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548332/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-table-using-puppeteer)